# Sqlite3 doesn't create table, and doesn't give error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have an application and I want it to create a table and insert a couple of values just starting.

My code to create the database table:

```
- (void) crearTablaConf {
sqlite3 *turutaDB;
NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *databasePath = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turuta.db"];

NSLog(@"path de la bbdd: %@",  databasePath);
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &turutaDB)==SQLITE_OK) { 
    NSLog(@"2 Base de datos creada y abierta con exito");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Ha fallado la apertura de la bbdd");
}


sqlite3_stmt *sentenciaTablaConf; 

NSString *queryTablaConf = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS configuraciones (id int(11) NOT NULL, idioma int(1),fecha date,PRIMARY KEY (id));";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(turutaDB, [queryTablaConf UTF8String], -1, &sentenciaTablaConf, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Consulta preparada ok"); //NO ERROR HERE
} else {
    NSLog(@"Consulta ha fallado al preparar: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(turutaDB));
}

sqlite3_finalize(sentenciaTablaConf);

sqlite3_stmt *sentenciaIniciar;
NSString *queryIniciar = @"insert into configuraciones (id, idioma, fecha) values ('1','0',NULL);";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(turutaDB, [queryIniciar UTF8String], -1, &sentenciaIniciar, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Consulta preparada ok");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Consulta ha fallado al preparar: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(turutaDB));
}     //HERE, SAYS "NO SUCH TABLE: CONFIGURACIONES"    

sqlite3_finalize(sentenciaIniciar);
}
```

I checked autocommit, and is on, so I don't find where the error is.

Comment: What is the full path of the sqllite file ?

Comment: /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/62752C2F-6BEE-4D0C-879C-7BE8F3F196F3/Documents/turuta.db

Comment: chek out my code and try...

Comment: What about the log in opening the DB?Is DB opened properly.From the path it is in the documents directory folder already i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *queryTablaConf = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS configuraciones (id int(11) NOT NULL, idioma int(1),fecha date,PRIMARY KEY (id));";
```

In your code after this line just added this block for successful creation of table and check once.

```
if (sqlite3_exec(turutaDB, queryTablaConf, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
```

Comment: I suppose I have to add the block instead of the block     `sqlite3_prepare_v2...`

Comment: And check once the database which you have used in properly opened or not before creating the new table "queryTablaConf".

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{


    NSString *databaseName = @"CPPPrograms.sqlite";




    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Dir :  %@ ",documentsDir);



    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];



    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success)
        return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package


    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];


    NSLog(@"%@",databasePathFromApp);

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];


    //[fileManager release];
}


- (void)getData
{

    NSString *databasePath;
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *documentsDir;
    NSArray *documentPaths;

    databaseName = @"CPPPrograms.sqlite";
    documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@",documentsDir);

    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM CppPrograms";

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            [PgmName removeAllObjects];
            [PgmHtml removeAllObjects];

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                [PgmName addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)]];

                [PgmHtml addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]];

                NSLog(@"%@",[PgmName description]);

                NSLog(@"%@",[PgmHtml description]);

            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Try this code as it is just changes table name and field name whatever your tablename....

Answer (score 0):

You missed `sqlite3_step()` statement.

Implement your method like:

```
- (void) crearTablaConf
{
   sqlite3 *turutaDB;
   NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *databasePath = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turuta.db"];

   if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &turutaDB)==SQLITE_OK)
   { 
      sqlite3_stmt *sentenciaTablaConf; 

      NSString *queryTablaConf = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS configuraciones (id int(11) NOT NULL, idioma int(1),fecha date,PRIMARY KEY (id));";

      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(turutaDB, [queryTablaConf UTF8String], -1, &sentenciaTablaConf, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
      {
          sqlite3_step(sentenciaTablaConf);
          sqlite3_finalize(sentenciaTablaConf);
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"Consulta ha fallado al preparar: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(turutaDB));
      }
      //Other stuffs
      sqlite3_close(turutaDBa);
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"Ha fallado la apertura de la bbdd");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
   NSString *docsDir;
   NSArray *dirPaths;
   sqlite3 *contactDB;
   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

   databasePath =[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdatabaseName.sqlite"];

   NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
   {
       const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

       if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
       {
           char *errMsg;
           const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LOCATION TEXT, CONDITION TEXT,HUMIDITY TEXT, WINDCONDI TEXT,PRESSURE TEXT, DEW TEXT, TEMP TEXT,LASTUP TEXT)";

           if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
           {
               NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
           }
           else{
               //Do anything here
           }

           sqlite3_close(contactDB);

       } else {
           NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
       }
   }
    else
    {
       // Do anything here
    }
```